# Android Studio Fontawesome Icons Not Displaying In HTML

Tags: android, html, css, android-studio, font-awesome

I have linked the file to my HTML document and I have the file in the assets folder of android studio but when I open the app, the icons just show as a rectangle with an "X" inside. I am using Fontawesome 5.6.1.[image: Screenshot of Android Studio]

[image: Image of Rectangles]

[image: Files]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot showing both the font and html file location?
You must use the relative path, not the full path.

Comment: @AnhaytAnanun Done.

Comment: Fix the URL in your CSS to point to the correct font file location and it will work.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Are you talking about the URL in the <link> tag? Because if so, I can't see the error in the URL.

Comment: You seem to have deleted the `.ttf`, `.eof`, `woff` and `.woff2` files starting with `fa-` from `/webfonts` folder. There are a total of 15 files. You need them if you want to serve fontawesome yourself. The alternative is to use their cdn: `https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css` (instead of local `all.min.css`). Read [this](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself) and [this](https://fontawesome.com/start).

Comment: If you're looking at removing external dependencies while keeping your app size low, you can probably skip `.eot`, `.ttf`, `.woff2` and `.svg` files and rely solely on [`.woff`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=woff), giving you a total coverage of more than `95%` for mobiles, which is probably what you're targeting.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Well, I need the files to be local since I'm releasing an app so I can't use the cdn. I also checked, and I do have all of the files in the webfonts folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185274/discussion-between-andrei-gheorghiu-and-lion-deluxe).